# Not Getting entry.S file in kernel v3.11.10-20

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

i have tried to find entry.S file in /usr/src/linux/arch/x86/kernel and also /usr/src/linux/arch/ia64/kernel but am not getting it.
I am using kernel version 3.11.10-20 and 64 bit machine
i am also not getting entry_32.S or entry_64.S
so plz help me

Comment: arch/ia64//kernel/entry.S

Comment: Can show output of `ls /usr/src/linux`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked out `v3.11` in my local Linux git repo and `arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S` and `arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S` are definitely both there.

Check out your own copy with:

`git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git`

and then:

`git checkout v3.11`

Comment: thank you @Alex i have downloaded the headers but forget to download the source of the kernel so i have now downloaded and got the files which i want thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

- i have downloaded the linux headers but it does not contain the actual implementation file so i didn't got entry_32.S and entry_64.S
- so based on the @Alex suggestion i searched out and found that i have not downloaded the source code and have downloaded only the headers finally after downloading the source code i found that files entry_32.S and entry_64.S